# How do I give an arduino an array from python through Serial?

Tags: python, arduino

So, I have a python program that uses pySerial to talk to my arduino uno through the serial port:

```py
upload_array = [0,1,0,0]

SERIAL = serial.Serial('COM4',9600)

while True:

  do_a_thing()

  SERIAL.write(b"f'{upload_array[0]},{upload_array[1]},{upload_array[2]},{upload_array[3]}\n'")
```

My arduino has code like this to read the incoming array:

```
int incoming_array[4];

void loop(){
  
  if (Serial.available() > 4){
    
    String incoming = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    for (int i; i < 4; i++){
      incoming_array[i] = incoming.substring(i,i).toInt();
    }
   }
   do_a_thing();
}
```

However, when I try to do anything with the array, it acts like it's empty.
What can I do to fix this?

Edit: Spelled a method wrong

Comment: this should not even compile. there is no function substing. please check your code for typos befor you post it here. is there any particular reason why you send an array of 0s and 1s as a string? just send those numbers.

Comment: You could take a look at this https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-an-int-to-bytes-in-python#:~:text=Use%20int.,the%20beginning%20of%20the%20array.

Comment: @Piglet I'm sending the array of 1s and 0s to tell the arduino which pins to make HIGH and which ones to make LOW. Each of the pins corresponds to an index of the array, so the arduino program reads the array and turns on or off the appropriate lights (this system works fine, I made a preset array and didn't use any serial communication and the program worked.) I'm sending them as a string because pySerial doesn't support println(), so I have to send it in bytes. However, I don't know how to convert the bytes to ints at the arduino, so I'm sending a string.

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem.
Here is my solutions in arduino forum: [Arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=714968.msg4805211#msg4805211)

But here is a example code:

Arduino:

```
//Arduino forum 2020 - https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=714968


int myArray[15]; //this value is the upgratable data
byte* 

ddata = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&myArray); // pointer for transferData()
size_t pcDataLen = sizeof(myArray);
bool newData=false;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);//baudrate
}

void loop() {
    checkForNewData();
    if (newData == true) {
        newData = false;
    }
    toPy(myArray[0],myArray[1],myArray[2],myArray[3],myArray[4],myArray[5],myArray[6],myArray[7],myArray[8],
    myArray[9],myArray[10],myArray[11],myArray[12],myArray[13],myArray[14],0,0,0,random(100)); //here write the send data
    }

void checkForNewData () {
    if (Serial.available() >= pcDataLen && newData == false) {
        byte inByte;
        for (byte n = 0; n < pcDataLen; n++) {
            ddata [n] = Serial.read();
        }
        while (Serial.available() > 0) { // now make sure there is no other data in the buffer
             byte dumpByte =  Serial.read();
             Serial.println(dumpByte);
        }
        newData = true;
    }
}


void toPy(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e,int f,
          int g,int h,int i,int j,int k,int l,
          int m,int n,int o,int p,int q,int r,int s)//19 datas
{
  //rpidata="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,111,0]";
String data="["+String(a)+","+String(b)+","+String(c)+","+String(d)+","+String(e)+","+String(f)+","+String(g)+","+String(h)+","+String(i)+","+
String(j)+","+String(k)+","+String(l)+","+String(m)+","+String(n)+","+String(o)+","+String(p)+","+String(q)+","+String(r)+","+String(s)+"]";
  delay(50);Serial.println(data);
}
```

And my python code (python 3.8):

```
#Arduino forum 2020 - https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=714968

import serial
from struct import *
import sys
import time
import random
import ast


try:
    ser=serial.Serial(baudrate='115200', timeout=.5, port='com8')    #!!!
except:
    print('Port open error')

time.sleep(5)#no delete!
while True:
    try:
        ser.write(pack ('15h',0,1,2,3,4,666,6,7,444,9,10,2222,12,13,random.randint(0,100)))#the 15h is 15 element, and h is an int type data
                                                                    #random test, that whether data is updated
        time.sleep(.01)#delay
        dat=ser.readline()#read a line data
        
        if dat!=b''and dat!=b'\r\n':
            try:                #convert in list type the readed data
                dats=str(dat)
                dat1=dats.replace("b","")
                dat2=dat1.replace("'",'')
                dat3=dat2[:-4]
                list_=ast.literal_eval(dat3) #list_ value can you use in program
                print(dat3)
            except:
                print('Error in corvert, readed: ', dats)
        time.sleep(.05)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    except:
        print(str(sys.exc_info())) #print error
        break

#the delays need, that the bytes are good order
```

If you a not int, or not 15 elements send, write over in (ser.write) line, for example '20l'. Read more for this : [Struckt Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)

Good luck!